# Why is it wrong to answer a question with a tautology? Isn't "2+2" correct when answering 'What is "2+2"'?

Tags: reference-request, semantics, identity, tautology, sense-and-reference

Many times in class, we are asked to answer, "What is 2+2?" or "What is the derivative of the function x?". It would not be the intended answer to write "2+2" or "The derivative of the function x". But, why not? A [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(rule_of_inference)) is technically a correct answer. Is there some formal definition of an "expression", that can distinguish between two different "expressions" that refer to the same "object"? I would like to know if other philosophers have thought of this problem, and which if any references apply.

Comment: What you are looking for is the idea behind the technical term [ground term](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_expression) of [rewrite systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting). Alternatively [normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_normal_form) in the
[lambda calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). No it's not trivial and this is not the best SE for it. Math, CS or theoretical CS would be more helpful

Comment: A tautology is not a correct answer even technically. What is correct is determined by the rules of linguistic practice, class in this case, and they prescribe, in particular, that the answers must be informative and relevant, see [Grice's communication maxims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle). Tautologies are not. The difference between two different expressions with the same referent is described by what Frege called sense, see [sense and reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_reference)

Comment: "It would not be the *intended* answer..." and "...technically a *correct* answer". It seems you're already aware there is a difference between these two. Are you asking why educators aren't more precise with their questions? Or are you asking **what** those intentions are? In either case, the question might fit better on Academia.SE or perhaps MathEducators.SE.

Comment: Now I show you a circle and ask: what is the ratio of the perimeter and the diameter? The answer is Pi. Now I ask: what is Pi? The answer is: it is the ratio of the perimeter and diameter of any circle. That's circular. You could also say that Pi is approximately 3.14, but it's not exactly 3.14, so there really is no better answer than the circular "Pi is the ratio of the perimeter and the diameter, and the ratio of the perimeter and the diameter is Pi."

Comment: Related question: [Is mathematics one big tautology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384861/is-mathematics-one-big-tautology)

Comment: @Stef: Ah, but there are [many other formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Formulae_yielding_%CF%80) for calculating pi, and you might answer in terms of those.

Comment: Heh heh. The answer is the answer to the question "Many times in class, we are asked..."

Comment: More wisdom in your comment @stef than most answers so far.  To use a Wittgenstein locution "the language game" played in different fields is different — even fields as close as basic arithmetic and basic algebra

Comment: ie sometimes one writes π as 3.14, sometimes as the more correct and sophisticated formulae that @kevin lists. **And sometimes we leave π as π**. (not to mention sometimes making pi into π as I've done or π into pi as you've ). IOW ppl answering condescendingly are only succeeding in displaying their ignorance of the non-triviality hiding behind the question

Comment: What would be the reason for the "Question" type of communicative sentences in general, if tautologies were acceptable? There is no reason to ask questions if tautologies are satisfactory. Notably, this question, can be answered that it is of course unacceptable, because it is unacceptable. To be a bit more constructive, isn't it the nature of a question which is at stake?

Comment: Grading comment: "Fails to demonstrate knowledge and mastery of the material.  In fact, fails to demonstrate awareness of the material.  0 points."

Comment: Many times in what class, please? Don't you expect different Answers if that was a "hard" subject such as maths or a "soft" one like philosophy?

Comment: "What is X?", for X=2+2, X=df/dx or similar, is actually a shorthand for "If you compute X, what result do you get?". Language has layers upon layers of "shorthanding". (Of course, know you can ask about "compute" and "result". Some answers and comments touch on that.)

Comment: Most of my math exams consisted of actions that needed to be performed, rather than questions that needed to be answered. E.g. "solve for x, where x=2+2", "derive y, where y=x^2".

Comment: I no longer can find access to a copy, but I remember Wilf's piece ["What is an Answer?"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321713) and can't help but feel it had some relevant opinions here

Comment: People asks to collect new information from the answer. Tautology answer like “2+2” for question “what is 2+2?” does not reveal any new information to the questioner. So even though its a logically correct answer but rationally incorrect.

Comment: *Why is it wrong to answer a question with a tautology? Isn't "2+2" correct when answering 'What is "2+2"'?*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The unstated assumption is that the person asking the question is asking for an answer that is in the simplest form. "What is 2+2?" could better be expressed as "What natural number is equal to 2+2?". The answer 4 is simpler than the description 2+2. "What is the derivative of the function x?" means, "What function, expressed in its simplest form, is identical to the derivative of x?"

In some cases, it might not be entirely obvious what the simplest form is. For example, [the square root of i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/what-is-sqrti) is a constant and looks simple enough, but it is possible to write it in different ways. It would be more precise to ask, "How can the square root of i be expressed without using any powers of i?"

In non-mathematical cases, arguably there is a distinct difference between identifying an individual by using a definite description, as contrasted with using their name or by indicating them in some direct way. To ask, "Who is the president of France?" is obviously a request for a name. To ask, "Who broke this vase?" is obviously a request for a name or some finger-pointing. We usually prefer to identify people using names rather than definite descriptions, though there is a theory of names which has it that names are a kind of definite description in disguise.

Comment: As an informal response in the context of informal math it's ok. Formally there are many ahems. Eg consider replacing in the question above "2+2" by "10 ** 10 **10" where ** denotes "raised to". More prosaically writing (ie "simplifying") Avogadro's number without scientific notation! A systematic response would need to use (something like) rewrite-systems or lambda-calculus.

Comment: Another issue is that a question "what is X, expressed in the simplest form" might well be X, but that would hardly be a tautology.  For example, the simplest-form answer to "what is nine divided by six" might be "one and one half", but the simplest-form answer to "what is five divided by six" would be "five sixths".  That X divided by six is X sixths may be a tautology, but the fact that the *simplest form* description of the answer is X sixths wouldn't be.

Comment: Hypothesis: This answer is false. Well is it? Prove: I might as well ask *what is 4*. The assumption is that 4 is the simplest term. But it is not. It is invariant over several representations, 2+2, or e.g. Roman IIII which is arguably more simple in the sense that it is homiconic, but it is not simpler to type. Corallary: There is no unique measure for simplicity in life. The simpelest answer would be *nothing*, inarguably, but that is not *satisfying*. Conclusion: The answer *might* be right, but it is resting on further unspoken assumptions, which is essentially what OP was asking about.

Comment: It is by the way incomprehensible why this answer was accepted while OP was clearly asking about reference to prior research (which should in effect exclude own research, for lack of a better word). The added insult "...is obviously..." is obviously not up to standards either. Although, intuition seems to be a bare necessity for communication, I think a more intuitive answer is possible.

Answer (score 19):

The teacher's goal when asking is not merely to obtain a correct answer (spoiler alert, because they already know the answer), but for the students to demonstrate knowledge, in order to make sure the lesson is assimilated. By merely parroting the question, the student demonstrates no knowledge.

Also, "the derivative of f is the derivative of f" is correct, but not very useful. If the teacher were to follow with a small application project that depends on derivation, like setting the strength of a toy catapult to hit a target with a ball, the student won't be able to do it. For this kind of project, they could succeed by trial and error, but imagine a plane engineers who, instead of  computing the amount of fuel for a plane to reach its destination, would tell you "listen, just jump in, we'll see what happen."

Comment: The slope of the graph of f at x=42 is the slope of the graph of f at x=42 :^)

Comment: @user well then the teacher can ask is it larger than 35 or smaller. (correct answer: larger or smaller or equal :-) )

Comment: Sort of a variation on [this old meme](https://www.google.com/search?q=find%20x%20meme&cad=h)...

Comment: @lalala yes and/or no - aladeen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYJ2w82WifU

Comment: So in other words, while the answer is not *logically* wrong, it is *pragmatically* wrong.

Comment: @lalala, to avoid [that](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77369/why-is-it-wrong-to-answer-a-question-with-a-tautology-isnt-22-correct-when#comment215133_77370), I guess one can say:  "Which is the correct sentence?  'The slope … is larger than 35', 'The slope … is smaller than 35', or 'The slope … equals 35.'"  I think enumeration of the possible answers, from which one must be chosen, is one of the few ways (the only way?) to express the acceptable answers explicitly, rather than on the basis of implicit context.

Answer (score 18):

### Short Answer

When you use talk about "expressions" and "objects" to which they refer, you are in the domain of [semiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics), [linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics), and the [philosophy of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language).
Semioticians talk about [symbol, reference, and referent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Meaning). [Analytical philosophers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy) tend to talk in terms of sense and reference. In computer science, there are variables that refer to memory addresses that refer to values.

But the question of why tautologies are not acceptable answers has much more to do with [implicature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature). [Tautologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(rule_of_inference)) while logically correct are [pragmatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) wrong! This is related to [Wittgenstein's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein) observation that meanings of words are contextually upon the [language-games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_game_(philosophy)) they are played in.

### Long Answer

Gottlob Frege in his *Über Sinn und Bedeutung* (On Sense and Reference) led the charge to address how to deal with [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics), or the meaning of words, and is considered the father of analytical philosophy, which is very driven since the [linguistic turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_turn) to understand how words contribute to philosophical ideas. In the twentieth century, many philosophers like [Bertrand Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Russell), [Saul Kripke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Kripke), [John Searle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Searle), and Ludwig Wittgenstein put their brilliant minds to these sorts of questions. I'll try to give you short version.

When one asks the question, 'What is 2+2?', the answer is not determined solely by logical function. There are motivations involved in questions and answers, and those constitute the rules of the 'language-game'. Human beings are considered [agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agency_(philosophy)) and as such manifest [intentionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentionality). What constitutes a correct answer is not solely logical or even grammatical (think of rhetorical questions, for instance), but rather are questions of [implicature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature). From the article:

> An implicature is something the speaker suggests or implies with an utterance, even though it is not literally expressed. Implicatures can aid in communicating more efficiently than by explicitly saying everything we want to communicate.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics) This phenomenon is part of pragmatics, a subdiscipline of linguistics. The philosopher H. P. Grice coined the term in 1975. Grice distinguished conversational implicatures, which arise because speakers are expected to respect general rules of conversation, and conventional ones, which are tied to certain words such as "but" or "therefore".[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics) Take for example the following exchange:

So, when one asks, 'What is 2+2'? There are several possible correct answers all of which rely on context.

> **A1.** '4.' (The goal when asking a young child during an arithmetic lesson.)
> **A2.** '2+2, Duh!' (The goal when responding to a math teacher to be a smart aleck.)
> **A3.** 'A binary functional expression of the summing operation.' (The goal when trying to show how arithmetic can be expressed with a predicate calclus.)
> **A4.** 'An idiom among philosophers to express the nature of analytical truth. (The goal when trying to express an understanding of the [analytical and synthetic divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction).
> **A5.** 'Okay, I get it. It's supposed to be easy, but you don't have to be a jerk and use sarcasm!' (When responding to someone who is trying to insult you when you make a mistake.)

Note that EVERY aforementioned answer is logically correct, but the real question of which is the appropriate response has nothing to do with grammar or logic, but rather the implicature. There are unspoken rules when communicating, the most famous being likely [Grice's Maxims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#Grice%27s_Maxims):

> In social science generally and linguistics specifically, the cooperative principle describes how people achieve effective conversational communication in common social situations—that is, how listeners and speakers act cooperatively and mutually accept one another to be understood in a particular way. As phrased by Paul Grice, who introduced it in his pragmatic theory,
>
> Make your contribution such as is required, at the stage at which it occurs, by the accepted purpose or direction of the talk exchange in which you are engaged.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics):45

So, why cannot one respond with a tautology like '2+2' when asked 'What is 2+2?' Well, one certainly can, so it's not a matter of [whether one can](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-epistemology/), but rather whether of one [should](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning-normativity/)!

Comment: The Grice reference reminds me of a joke about teaching English as a foreign language: if a teenage boy asks a teenage girl "Have you seen the latest Star Wars Movie yet?" the correct translation is often something like "Do you want to spend a couple of hours with me in the dark?"

Comment: @alephzero lol Point well made.

Answer (score 8):

Language is about communication, not formal logic.

Most of the time, a question is asked to gain information. Usually, the information desired is about the subject of the question (e.g. “When's the train gonna get here?” is requesting information about the train), though sometimes the asker might want indirect information (e.g. whether the askee knows the answer to a question), or to accomplish something (e.g. the Socratic method of teaching). This situation has aspects of all three, though mainly the last two.

A trivial tautology communicates no information (about the question's subject, anyway), so is not (usually) a useful answer to a question. In the sense that it doesn't help with what the question asker intended answers to be useful for, the answer is wrong.

Comment: Exactly - a tautology does not convey any information. If someone asks you "What is a Neuron?" - you will usually try to provide some new information so they can understand what the Word "Neuron" refers to.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but we encourage users to use references like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/), the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/), and [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/) to strengthen the quality of responses.

Answer (score 5):

It is not wrong to state that P is P, but it is implicitly assumed so, according to [Aristotle's *law of identity*](https://oregonstate.edu/instruct/phl201/modules/Philosophers/Aristotle/aristotle_laws_of_thought.html).

So, in case of having such type of question, "What is P?", an answer of the form "P is P" is not necessary. One can assume that being it not the expected answer, in most cases the answer will probably be wrong.

Remark that it is not the proposition ("P is P") that is wrong: it is the answer that is wrong. The error could be considered to come from a [*red herring/avoiding the issue* fallacy](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Red-Herring) (the same as answering "bananas are yellow": it is true that bananas might be yellow, but that's not the expected answer).

Comment: Aristotle's LoI is the red-herring here  : Just replace "2+2" in q by "2+3" and in answer by "3+2" LoI stops applying but I guess his teacher remains dissatisfied! As @Bumble said it's a q about simplification. And as I've said to bumble and to OP simplification is not a simple matter

Answer (score 5):

This answer is based primarily on pragmatics, a field in the intersection of linguistics and philosophy of language.

You are right that the answer "2+2" to the question "what does 2+2 equal" is correct. The issue is that such a tautological answer does not help the other speaker, and so violates our basic assumptions about how a conversation should function.

Essentially, unless we have evidence to the contrary, we assume that our conversation partners are cooperating with us in conveying information. This is called the [Cooperative principle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/implicature/#GricTheo) and is summed up in Grice's Maxims:

1. Maxim of Quality: Try to make your contribution one that is true. Do not say what you believe is false. Do not say that for which you lack adequate evidence.
2. Maxim of Quantity: Make your contribution as informative as is required (for the current purposes of the exchange). Do not make your contribution more informative than is required.
3. Maxim of Relevance: Be relevant.
4. Maxim of Manner: Be perspicuous (despite being self-violating, this is the usual framing). Avoid obscurity of expression. Avoid ambiguity. Be brief (avoid unnecessary prolixity). Be orderly.

A tautological answer gives less information than is required (failing the maxim of quantity), and is not relevant (failing the maxim of relevance). The question was asked expecting a good faith cooperative answer, and instead we found out that our conversation partner was not communicating cooperatively. This is not the answer we wanted or expected, hence the listener feels put out.

Non-cooperative communication does of course occur in the wild. Many jokes are based on a certain amount of non-cooperativity (showing that it isn't even always viewed as a social faux pas), as of course is lots of deliberately manipulative communication (i.e. propaganda).

Comment: Just a nitpick on your introductory sentence: There literally is a branch called philosophy of language and many philosophers have contributed to theories of communication, like C.S. Peirce, Cassirer, Wittgenstein, Ayers, Ryle, Habermas. Ironically, Grice was a philosopher as well, so the answer is based in philosophy which has been adapted in linguistic theory ;)

Comment: ah ok, I'd usually heard Grice described as a Pragmatist within linguistics, rather than a Philosopher of Language, but that could easily be due to my coming at it primarily from that direction. I've reworded that sentence

Comment: It's a common trope that philosophers are claimed to be a "social/political scientist", "economist", "mathematician/logician", "biologist", "linguist", etc. because they provided influential contributions to these fields. It does not help philosophy's academic and social standing, as you can imagine. Did you know that Adam Smith wrote his major works giving birth to modern economics as moral philosophy, for example? Grice, in particular, taught philosophy at Oxford and UC Berkeley and made major contributions to the study of ethics, metaphysics, and artificial intelligence as well.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but we encourage users to use references like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/), the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/), and [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/) to strengthen the quality of responses.

Comment: link added to wikipedia. I don't have more specific sources available to hand, although if someone else does, they're welcome to edit them in

Comment: @Tristan: I replaced the link with the corresponding entry in the Stanford Encyclopedia. It starts with the Cooperative Principle and the maxims and continues with some more technical implications of them (pun intended - the main entry is "implicature"). The contributions there are written and kept up to date by professional philosophers working in the corresponding field and a pretty good go-to source.

Answer (score 3):

The answers this question is asking about give linguistic *identity*, when the questions ask to resolve the *denotation* (or linguistic *reference*). See Frege's "Sense and Reference" and Russell's "On Denoting". To use Russell's example, if I ask "What is the Morning Star?", the question is about the referred-to object: the planet Venus. Clearly the question-asker already knows the linguistic utterance "the Morning Star" — the question-asker used that very utterance in forming his question — so returning that utterance as an answer cannot fulfill the 'what is...' which seeks a resolution. "The Morning Star" *would only* be a correct answer to the question "What is the other name for the planet Venus", because then we have reversed the process: asked about the alternate linguistic utterance that *refers to* or *denotes* the planet.

Answer (score 2):

- Arguably, 2+2 = 4 is also a tautology.

Let's admit that
(a) the succcessor of n is n+1
(b) 2 is the successor of 1
(c) 3 is the successor of 2
(d) 4 is the successor of 3
(e) addition is associative

We therefore get

2+2 = 4

is equivalent to 2+(1+1) = 4

is equivalent to (2+1) + 1 = 4

is equivalent to 3+1 = 4

is equivalent to 4=4.

If 4=4 is a tautotolgy ( or at least a vacuously true statement) and if 2+2 = 4 is equivalent to 4=4, then, 2+2 = 4 is also a tautology.

- ***However, though equivalent objectively, not alll tautologies are equally informative subjectively***. A young child may not know that 2+2 and 4 have the same denotation; he may not know that, though conceptually different, " the sum of 2 and 2 " and " the successor of 3 " refer to the same object.

In the same way, supposing f is a the function such that f(x)=2x.  One may understand the expression ' the derivative of g(x) = x² ", but may not know at the same time that " f " and " the derivative of g " refer to the same object ( for there is a conceptual / intensional distinction betweeen f and g).  So being able to say that " f = g' " shows one possesses some knowledge that a person only capable of saying " *f = f* " does not have.

- In the same way , the inspector that is capable to say " the murderer is John Doe" is much more capable than the inspector that is only capable to say " the murderer is the murderer".
- **Conclusion : teachers try to make sure we know that 2 expressions have the same referent/denotation , in spite of the fact these expressions do not have the same intension ( = conceptual content)**

Answer (score 2):

In linguistics, the study of meaning is often broken down into **semantics** (the intrinsic value of an utterance) and **pragmatics** (how people actually use language). "2+2 = 2+2" is a semantically correct statement, but generally not a pragmatically useful one.

In particular, when someone asks a question, they generally have a purpose behind it. That purpose might be to gain new knowledge ("okay, can you show me an example? if you use these new axioms to define addition, what's 2+2?"), or to test whether a student has learned the material ("quick, tell me, what's 2+2?"), or for another reason completely separate from arithmetic ("the Party says that 2+2=5, so tell me Winston, what's 2+2?").

But in all of these situations, "2+2 = 2+2" doesn't satisfy that purpose. It doesn't provide the questioner with new information, it doesn't demonstrate that a student has learned how to do arithmetic, and it doesn't demonstrate obedience to the Party.

And since it doesn't satisfy the purpose, it's not a *useful* answer to the question, even if it's technically a *correct* one. Philosophers generally concern themselves with semantics more than pragmatics, but language is generally used for a purpose, and in day-to-day life, fulfilling the speaker's purpose matters just as much as the literal truth values of what is said.

Consider also: "Can you pass the salt?" "Yes, I am capable of passing the salt." In most situations, the asker isn't just curious whether they're *capable* of it (which most people are), but actually wants the salt. So expressing capability, while semantically correct, is not pragmatically useful.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but we encourage users to use references like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/), the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/), and [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/) to strengthen the quality of responses.

Comment: I'm upvoting, because I encourage users to make references to [George Orwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Orwell)'s [1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_(book)) and [its IngSoz Party](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ing-Soz)'s math curriculum. The underlying more philosophical reference to the different messages in a single utterance is also appreciated, since I have asked about it on linguistics.SE and another answer here concedes that it' s noteworthy; anyway I think you missed the question by a bit with regards to the pragmatics of rethorically repeating a question.

Answer (score 2):

A tautology is unlikely to be a correct answer in this case, because it’s not on the answer sheet and you want to pass the test/quiz/worksheet.

You could of course write “four”, but that isn’t the answer the teacher is looking for and so will likely get points taken off, if not outright marked incorrect. 2+2 is 100% incorrect.

As with everything else, context is king.  The question is asked for a reason, the answer either serves that reason or not, and the one asking the question will judge the answer as sufficient or not.

2+2 = You’re missing the vig, and I’m gonna break your legs.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but we encourage users to use references like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/), the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/), and [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/) to strengthen the quality of responses.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is incorrect as it observes an absence of variation between the original assertion and that which follows it.  It is the variation, which allows for a contrast through difference, which reflects itself under the "correct" answer given one phenomenon is expressed under a new form.  This new form allows for a distinction between the original assertion and the new assertion, that of the answer, which allows for definition.

Definition occurs through contrast, contrast through difference, thus definition occurs through difference.  All answers are defined through their difference to the original assertion with this definition being that of the answer itself.  To answer a question is to give proof, to give proof is to give definition of a state of being.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but we encourage users to use references like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/), the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/), and [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/) to strengthen the quality of responses.

Comment: Okay, sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

It is not wrong to answer 2+2 (or even 2x2, or 4x1) to the question "what is 2+2?".

Note that the question is neither philosophical, mathematical, nor logical, but purely pedagogical.

Math teachers have trouble asking what they really want the students to answer. In fact, it is rather puzzling that some children actually understand that the answer the teacher wants to hear is 4; these children are the ones that become later "good at math". It's not that they think "2+2" would be an incorrect answer; they just know that *it's not the answer the teacher wants*.

The real tragedy is that most of the students (not the good ones) will *understand* that 2+2 is an incorrect answer and this will cause great harm to their understanding.

As a math teacher, I have, once, presented the following solution to the exercise "solve x^2 = 1 for x": "1 and -1 are obviously solutions, and we know that a degree-two polynomial equation in one variable has at most two solutions, so we are done". A lot of students felt cheated, that I wasn't giving the right answer; they wanted me to copy-paste the usual solution with Delta.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your stated question to if the teacher had instead asked "What are some other expressions that equal 2+2?".

While "2 + 2 = 2 + 2" is a True statement, it is not the "correct" answer because there is an unspoken implied extension to statements of this kind in education: "What is 2+2 in the commonly given most simplified form?"

Through your use of the term "technically correct", you suggest awareness of this. There are infinite expressions you can enter on the right side of the "=" to produce a True equation. But the correct answer is typically unique.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.